# Python - Converting string data into dataframe

Tags: python

I have called on some API and had the following return data format in string.

```
{'data': {'totalItems': 2,
  'startDate': '2017-09-28 ',
  'endDate': '2017-10-01 ',
  'items': [{'IDNum': '763192',
    'url': 'https://www.mask.com/api/v1/763192',
    'JoinDate': '2017-09-30'},
   {'IDNum': '763193',
    'url': 'https://www.mask.com/api/v1/763192',
    'JoinDate': '2017-09-29'}]}}
```

i will like to convert this string into a tabular/dataframe format with IDNum, url and JoinDate as headers.

I have tried panda to convert it into CSV but everything appears in one cell.

Thank you.

Comment: What _exactly_ is your expected output? What happens to `data`, `startdate`, etc.?

Comment: I dont really need the data and startdate. startDate and endDate are actually parameters i passed into the api. The subsequent information is what i need, RafaelC's answer solves it. I didnt know existent of  ast.literal_eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string

```
s = """{'data': {'totalItems': 2,
  'startDate': '2017-09-28 ',
  'endDate': '2017-10-01 ',
  'items': [{'IDNum': '763192',
    'url': 'https://www.mask.com/api/v1/763192',
    'JoinDate': '2017-09-30'},
   {'IDNum': '763193',
    'url': 'https://www.mask.com/api/v1/763192',
    'JoinDate': '2017-09-29'}]}}"""
```

you can use `ast.literal_eval` to get a dict and `pandas` to get the `df`

```
import ast

pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(s)['data']['items'])


    IDNum   JoinDate    url
0   763192  2017-09-30  https://www.mask.com/api/v1/763192
1   763193  2017-09-29  https://www.mask.com/api/v1/763192
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to convert only a *portion* of your data structure:

```
pd.DataFrame(data['data']['items'])
#    IDNum    JoinDate                                 url
#0  763192  2017-09-30  https://www.mask.com/api/v1/763192
#1  763193  2017-09-29  https://www.mask.com/api/v1/763192
```